# Creating factorial - if, else statement with error messages in java

Tags: java, if-statement, factorial

I need to create factorial code with if, else statement, where user input must be WHOLE POSITIVE NUMBER GREATER THAN ZERO. Otherwise it will shows an error message to ask user for entering whole positive number greater than zero.
I started with this code:

```java
System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();

    if (number<=0)
        {
            for (count=1; count<=number; count++)
            factorial = factorial*count;

            System.out.println("Factorial of your number is: "+factorial);
            System.out.println();
        }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive whole number greater than 0");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The code is working fine for the factorial and error message for entering zero or negative number. So the only thing I need is to define the WHOLE number for the error message.

Comment: What do you mean "define the WHOLE number for the error message"? `nextInt` throws an error if the number is not `int`..

Comment: Reverse the logic in your if. Change it to `if(number>0)`. Also, do handle the case of `factorial(0) = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that yor are putting the wrong condion for the if loop for the `number` 
As `if(number<=0)` will take all number less than or equal to 0,but as per your condition you want a number greater than 0,so change the code as below::

```
 try{
   System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
   int number=sc.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception ex)  {
       System.out.pritnln("please enter a valid number");
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }


if (number>0)
    {
        for (count=1; count<=number; count++)
        factorial = factorial*count;

        System.out.println("Factorial of your number is: "+factorial);
        System.out.println();
    }
else
{
    System.out.println("Enter a positive whole number greater than 0");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I have mistaken, but it still doesn't work, when the user enter number e.g. 6.4 or 9.747. How can I change the code for the whole number as well?

Comment: Can you define a whole number is it greater than 0 or greater or equal to 0?? @user2441860

Comment: @user2441860: an int is a whole number. Define what you mean by "a whole number", and explain what is missing, as you've already been asked.

Comment: i need to show eeror message when the user's input is 5,23 instead of 5.

Comment: If anything you will input except a integer it will automatically throw Number formatException,and you can print something like that in the catch block.

Comment: Now try the above codes I have added a try catch for ya which will check for whether integer is the input and throw a exception with a prinln otherwise @user2441860

Answer (score -1):

Simply put a `try` block around your call to `nextInt()`, and if an exception is thrown, tell the user, like so:

```
int number = 0;
boolean ok = true;
try {
    number = sc.nextInt();
} catch (Exception ex) { //user did not enter a valid integer
    ok = false;
}

if (number>0 && ok) {
    //...
} else {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive whole number greater than 0");
}
```

Comment: It red underlines the catch statement

Comment: What are you catching,there should be a exception specified in the catch statement,please correct if I m wrong. @Andrew Sun

Comment: Sorry, I program in C#, forgot Java needs to explicitly declare the exception type. Fixed now.